# How to make WebView load local resources instead of downloading them from server?

Tags: java, android, html, android-studio, webview

I have a webview app which load resources(css,js,images) from server. I would like it to load resources from the assets folder in the app. How can i do that?.

I tried using: `<img class="after-splash" src="file:///android_asset/image.png">` but nothing works. I already have an asset folder in the app\src\main

Comment: I already have an asset folder and the first html file being loaded by the webview comes from that asset folder. The main problem here is I want those files which have been stored in the server(online) to load resources from the asset folder in the app

Answer (score 0):

If webview is loading a html page from assets folder and the code segment you mentioned is within the html file, relative file path will work fine

```
<img class="after-splash" src="image.png">
```

Also watchout for [CORS errors](https://html.com/attributes/img-crossorigin/) if it is still not loading

```
<img class="after-splash" src="image.png" crossorigin="anonymous">

image.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous'
```

Comment: I have no problem loading html page from assets folder. What i want is to load html file from server but its resources should be loaded from the assets folder in the app instead of being loaded from the server

Comment: Have you checked logs for any errors while trying to load it from file:///android_asset/image.png

Comment: Here is what i found: Not allowed to load local resource: file:///android_asset/delivery.png

Comment: You should set a flag in webviewclient -or so- to enable that.

Comment: Can you explain how? @blackapps

Comment: Android Studio tells you all possible methods and properties. Just look around and choose the one(s) that look right. The ones with allow or load or local or resource or such.